# how to make splash screen with action button in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I want to create splash screen with action button to close that splash screen in angularjs like [Forbes.com](http://www.forbes.com) as follow.

I'm trying to do with ng-cloak but that splash is hidden when original page is coming up. That's not what I want. What I want is I want to display that splash screen no matter what happen and that will be hidden when user click button on that page.

**html**

```
div.splash(ng-cloak)
  h2 Loading
div(ng-controller="myCtrl", ng-cloak)
    //original page
```

**CSS**

```
.splash {
    display: none;
}

[ng-cloak].splash {
    display: block !important;
}

.splash {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%; 
    filter: alpha(opacity=60);
    opacity: 0.6;
    background: #000;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Use ng-if to display splash screen in starting.

Answer (score 0):

Below code will help you in achieving your goals.

```js
angular.module('app', [])

.controller('MainCtrl', function () {
    this.isContinue = false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">
    <div ng-if="!main.isContinue">
        <p>Splash screen</p>
        <button ng-click="main.isContinue = true">Continue to site</button>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="main.isContinue">
        <p>Welcome to home page !</p>
        <button ng-click="main.isContinue = false">Back to splash screen</button>
    </div>
</div>
```